# Multiple repositories as one in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, repository-design

I'm in trouble figuring out how to organize a mercurial repository for a Django project I'm starting. This is the current configuration:

```
.
├── .hg
├── docs
├── manage.py
├── project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── requirements.txt
```

For how my workflow is, I'd prefer to keep the activities related to project and docs separated. Having two dedicated repositories could be a way to solve the issue, but then I should clone two repos if I want both the docs and the project, while I'd be optimal to clone only one all-inclusive repo, as the one of the picture above.

Is it possible to obtain what I want, and how to reorganize project, docs and repositories?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to nest repositories under a parent one. See [Mercurial Subrepository](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository).

**BUT** - this is not a good practice. See [FeaturesOfLastResort](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FeaturesOfLastResort) explanation here.

In our R&D, we have many repositories, and when needed, the developers are already used to cloning the needed ones (2 or more) for the relevant activity.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can have repositories nested inside parent repo. It is considered to be a bad practice. I think you should split your docs and code into separate repositories.

You can add [hooks](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Hook) on desired operations so actions taken in one repository could automatically be executed in the other. In addition to that you can also use [aliases](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/AliasExtension) for operations on both repos, so you'll have special commands for operations in both repos.

To solve cloning issues you can create script which will clone both repos in desired folder.